# Where to place my button for intent?

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

I have created an app with a tutorial. Its now quiz time, I know what to do but how do I determine which class should have my button to open an intent for a URL that are in the JSON data.

The following Class are:

> MainActivity.java -
>    - *Creates an ArrayList showing the results in a ListView* 
>     Earthquake.java - 
>    - *Constructs Strings, Double & Longs in to an object*
>     EarthquakeAdapter.java - 
>    - *Use GetView to inflate the ListView with the Earthquake objects*
>     QueryUtils.java - 
>    - *JSON data where extracts to ojects and turned in to Double, Strings & Longs.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use intent in both classes namely MainActivity.java or EarthquakeAdapter.java.